# Why buffer tab plugin not work with Neovim 0.4

Tags: neovim, buffers, tabbed-user-interface

I installed the latest Neovim 0.4 from scratch, install 'vim-plug', then add only 4 lines to my init.vim:

```
call plug#begin('d:/neovim/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'ap/vim-buftabline'
set hidden
call plug#end()
```

Then create two buffers with

```
:badd aaa
:badd bbb
```

Then it looks like this

[image]

I trid different plugins like [vim-buftabline](https://github.com/ap/vim-buftabline), [vim-wintabs](https://github.com/zefei/vim-wintabs), [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline), same issue, it must be problem with the configuration, what do I miss?

Comment: I dont use vim-plug, but do you maybe need to `:PlugInstall` or something?

Comment: Yes, I have `:PlugInstall`, otherwise even the tab '[No Name]' won't be exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found why. There's a command to disable the tab.

```
:Guitabline 0
```

And the [document](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/equalsraf/neovim-gui-shim/master/doc/nvim_gui_shim.txt)